# Technically possible to run meteor unit tests against running server?

Tags: unit-testing, docker, meteor

Locally I'm running `meteor test --driver-package practicalmeteor:mocha --port 4001` to run my unit tests, which is refreshing each time I am changing files. So this is ok for developing.

In my CI process I would like to do first unit tests, and if they are passing, I do a `meteor build` and deploy the application to a docker container. This is working, but running `meteor test --once --driver-package dispatch:mocha` as a CI stage will always take some minutes (5-15 minutes) each time to start up a meteor instance, which is not very practical for unit tests. Working, but takes way too much time...

So my idea would be if it is technically possible to run a kind of meteor test server as a docker container, which is already running. In the CI unit test stage I would pull the repository (files) and run the tests with those immediately.

But is this possible with meteor at all?